# Why would this table allow a PK id of 0?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In SQL Server 2008 R2, I have a table that allows 0 as a foreign key. This is odd because a primary key constraint is specified, and the `IDENTITY(1,1)` descriptor is also used.

When the first record is inserted to the table, it's PK (`RegionID`) is 0.

I don't have `IDENTITY-INSERT` turned ON when I am doing an insert. (Normal operation)

Here's the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tdfRegions](
    [RegionID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RegionName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [RegionDescription] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tdfRegions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RegionID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

I have been acting under the assumption that the first record inserted to this table would have a `RegionID` of 1.

```
INSERT INTO 
    tdfRegions (RegionName, RegionDescription, Active) 
VALUES 
    ('test','test', 1)
```

Produces:

```
RegionID   RegionName   RegionDescription   Active
    0      test         test                   1
```

Why might this be happening?

**EDIT:**

Ok, I've got a little more background information here. Someone ran a

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
GO
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DELETE FROM ?'
GO
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
GO
```

To clear the database when it was first created. Could this have been responsible?

Comment: Check if you have `INSTEAD OF INSERT` triggers.

Comment: If you do a `dbcc checkident(tdfRegions, reseed, 0)` after `truncate table tdfRegions` you will get a `0` as first value. If the reseed is done after `delete from tdfRegions` it will be a `1`. Are you reseeding your table?

Comment: This script shows all triggers created on `dbo.tdfRegions` table: `SELECT t.is_instead_of_trigger, t.* FROM sys.triggers t WHERE t.parent_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.tdfRegions');`

Comment: OK - it's odd, and I can't reproduce it - but why is this a problem, really? When you insert a new row, just grab whatever value is being used by the `IDENTITY` column - I don't care if it's 0, 1, 1000000 or whatever - it's just an arbitrary number....

Comment: marc_s - it's important to understand why something like this might be  happening; not having a good mental model of the technology you are using can lead you to making assumptions that can prove harmful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason it you could end up with 0 in the RegionID is --

when you truncate the table and reseed the identity to 0 using below command

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('tdfRegions', RESEED, 0)
```

If you then insert into the table with your insert block, it will be RegionID = 0.

[image]

Comment: Or even easier, do 'DBCC CHECKIDENT('tdfRegions', RESEED)'.  The reseed function does not require a new_reseed_value.  You might think it would be set back to the original, it is not.  It is set back to 0 if you do not set a specific value.

Answer (score 1):

The ways I know to reset the PK are:
a) use truncate
But that would put the see back to 1
b) use something like:
DBCC CHECKIDENT (MyTable, RESEED, 1)
If you used a 0 instead of a 1 in the last statement, that would get the seed set to 0.
Someother people talking about this.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/ca0db3d2-e3ae-46ce-b8f0-bfc3bf95a509/